# driver.find_element_by_css_selector get error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.btn_more').click()
```

I am able to click the **get more** link using above code

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn_more">get more </a>
```

but how to click on **followers** link?

```
<div class="my_show__info">
<a class="my_show__link j_get_follow" href="javascript:;" data-follow="followers"> 90</a>
<a class="my_show__link j_get_follow" href="javascript:;" data-follow="following"> 33</a>
</div>
```

Comment: fisrt code is   :   <a href="javascript:;" class="btn_more">more</a>

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Question header says `driver.find_element_by_css_selector get error`, Code trial is of `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")` and HTML of `<a>` tag.

Comment: i want use driver.find_element  run javascript  about  code : followers adn following .

Comment: i have use xpath  solve the problem . thanks ! hehe

Answer (score 0):

you can form a xpath and click on the link as mentioned below. if you want using CSS. convert the following xpath with css.

```
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//div[@class='my_show__info']/a[@data-follow="followers"])).click()
```

I am not good with CSS but I guess following should work.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class='my_show__info']>a[data-follow='followers']').click()
```

Comment: thanks, i  have use   firefox  addons firebug  find it  how to work.   also  past some time , has already known how to find it.